# How to include a prebuilt "*.a" library (from tensorflow) to my android NDK project with no Android.mk file?

Tags: android, tensorflow, android-ndk, ndk-build

I'm trying to compile my application to use tensorflow C++ library after building `lintensorflow_core.a` into my NDK application. The application has the main java layer, that communicates with the NDK component. In that NDK component, I'm looking to call the tensorflow as such: `using namespace ::tensorflow::ops;  // NOLINT(build/namespaces)`

I've seen bunch of links on how to do it with `Android.mk` file. But apparently, that does not gets created anymore in the new version of android studio. If it is possible with just `Android.mk` and `ndk-build` command, that would be great as well. However, the combination of `Android.mk` and `ndk-build` has also failed me. The output basically nothing.

I did have plenty of variation of Android.mk file and here's one of them:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
TENSORFLOW_HOME := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../tensorflow
TENSORFLOW_CORE := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../tensorflow/tensorflow/core
TENSORFLOW_OPS := $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../../../tensorflow/tensorflow/core/ops

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := tensorflow
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(TENSORFLOW_HOME)/tensorflow/contrib/makefile/gen/lib/android_armeabi-v7a/libtensorflow-core.a

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -static -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--allow-multiple-definition -Wl,--whole-archive
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -std=c++11 -I$(TENSORFLOW_HOME)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(TENSORFLOW_OPS)
TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

But this has been a total failure. Could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: How do you build 'that NDK component'? Maybe you simply put the cpp files in some jni directory, and let Android Studio compile them into an so file and pack it into the apk?

Comment: @AlexCohn That's another thing, I'm looking to work on this without actually moving files around. So, both the compiled headers, and .a from tensorflow will just sit in their own project space, as well as the NDK component for the app, and the app itself.

Comment: I understand your answer as 'yes'. In this case, with Android Studio 3, you will receive a message that explains how to move from the deprecated NDK support to new, which expects **Android.mk** for your code, too.

Comment: Have you been able to solve your issue? Could you share it?